# jump to bottom of ANY page the user is currently using

Tags: php, wordpress, page-jump

**edit: using wordpress:**

I have a menu button called Contact me, that leads to a contact me page.

I also have 8 pages, with a contact me form at the very bottom.

Is there a way to change that menu button name contact me, to scroll down to the end of the page in use, no matter what that page is?!

the difference here is i dont have one constant jump to point, but the bottom of any page the user is currently using.

Comment: It would help knowing what context this is in, programming languages used, OS, ui framework etc. As it is now it is almost impossible to answer the question.

Comment: point taken! using wordpress. therefore php. ill edit just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Set the link for the contact me menu to `href="#contactmeform"` or something similar, then wrap your entire contact form in a div with `id="contactmeform"`

This way the navigation link will take you to the element with that ID on the page you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Make the href on the anchor text point to `"/contact#contact"`

Then add id="contact" on your contact form. This will the hash on the anchor will be used to scroll the page to that anchor point.

Comment: Just to expand, you could also have an ID called id="bottom" as some sites do. id="top" is also a common usage hack to scroll to the top. (Although empty # does the same thing)

Comment: the link `/contact#contact` would not take the user to the bottom of the page if they were, lets say, on the about us page, then the link would need to be `/about#contact`.  I would suggest just linking to `#contact` so it will work on every page

Comment: Yep. I skimmed the question.

Comment: Just make the link lead to `/#contact` instead and you'll be fine, like @JacobCarter wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<a href="#bottom">Contact Me</a>
<a name="bottom">
<form id=contactMe>
</form>
</body>
```